# Installing Docker on Ubuntu 15.04, failure to update

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, docker

I'm struggling to use `sudo apt-get update` on:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid
```

I'm working through a virtual machine on Illumina Basespace which could be part of the problem (except the whole point of basespace is to use docker so I feel like it should be possible).

I'm getting the error:

```
...
Ign https://get.docker.io docker/main Translation-en
Fetched 6,507 B in 10s (606 B/s)
W: Conflicting distribution: http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/snapshots/3.12.0 InRelease (expected wheezy/snapshots but got wheezy)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/vivid/stable/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/vivid/stable/binary-armhf/Packages  HttpError404
W: Failed to fetch http://basespace-apt.s3.amazonaws.com/dists/bfs/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://basespace-apt.s3.amazonaws.com/dists/bfs/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."
```

If I try to visit the links in question there doesn't appear to be an ubuntu/dists/vivid folder at that address, this could be part of the issue?

When I try to install Docker using

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

it tells me it is unable to find the package, I think because the update didn't work properly.

I'm new to all this but I was wondering if anyone can provide any help? I've tried lots of different stuff from forums like this but none of them are working.

Comment: ubuntu 15.04. is since February 2016 EOL https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: But everything says to update you use sudo apt-get update, which won't work, seemingly because the version in Illumina Basespace is out of date. Do you know of a way to update it without using that command?

Comment: I managed to get it to upgrade to the newest release which appears to be 15.10, is there a way to make it change to the newer versions such as 17? I'm still getting the same error with 15.10 (wily)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docker offocial website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#os-requirements) , docker can be installed on Ubuntu 14.04,16.04 and 16.10

> **OS requirements**
>
> To install Docker, you need the 64-bit version of one of these Ubuntu versions:
>
> Yakkety 16.10
>
> Xenial 16.04 (LTS)
>
> Trusty 14.04 (LTS)
>
> Docker CE is supported on both x86_64 and armhf architectures.

also the `apt` fail because of the `wheezy` source on your ubuntu distribution:

```
W: Conflicting distribution: http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/snapshots/3.12.0 InRelease (expected wheezy/snapshots but got wheezy)
```